# I need to stamp a image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to stamp a image using Jquery. It is almost done, but I'm not able to define a ID to the obtained clone. please help me. My code is given below:

```
//Make element click    
     $(".drag").click(function(ev){

        var currentid = ev.target.id.substr(4,5)
         test11 = $(this).attr('id');           
         $("#frame").css("cursor","url(images/Stamp_icon.png),auto");           
        correct = "#"+test11;           
        cloneobj = true;    
     });

     //stamp the object when click

     $("#frame").click(function(e) {

        if(e.pageX>=160 && e.pageX<=950){
            if(e.pageY>=210 && e.pageY<=580){
                if(cloneobj == true && correct != "null"){ 
                clonecounter++                  
        var o = {           
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY            
    };

    var obj = $(correct).clone().appendTo('#frame').show(0).offset(o);
    clonearr.push(obj)
     $(correct).attr("class","duplicateClone"); 
    }
     }                  
        }
         })


    //Delete obj    
    $(".delbtn").click(function(){
            correct = "null";
            $("#frame").css("cursor","default");
            if(clonecounter>0){
            $(clonearr[clonecounter]).remove();
            clonearr.pop(clonecounter)
            clonecounter--;
            }
    })
```

Comment: please make a js fiddle of the codes

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correcty then changing this line

```
var obj = $(correct).clone().appendTo('#frame').show(0).offset(o);
```

to this would probably help

```
var obj = $(correct).clone().attr("id", "newId").appendTo('#frame').show(0).offset(o);
```

Or whatever id you want to give the new clone.